# Convert tiff to jpg in php?

Tags: php, image, gd

I have a server which holds TIFF images. Most clients can read and display TIFF images, so there's no problem. However, some clients can't handle this format but can handle JPG.
I thought of using PHP's GD library to do a server side conversion for clients without TIFF reading abilities. But I noticed GD can't read TIFF files too.

Imagick not working in windows, My idea was to create an imageFetcher.php which gets as a parameter the actual image the client wants. It checks the client's type and if needed converts the image and outputs a JPG, otherwise it simply outputs the TIFF.

does anyone have any idea on how I could do such a thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give a look to Image Magick

Comment: @MikeBrant Who said that they are using them in a web context? Just because a http server is being used doesn't mean they are on a web site. What if they are working with vendors who need TIFF files and they just happen to be transferring them over http?

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle Because the OP was talking about problems with client browsers being able to display TIFF files.  Certainly if you are working in digital imagery you can have TIFF available for download or whatever, but it makes no sense whatsoever to use them for web display.

Comment: @MikeBrant Where do they mention browser?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the forum at http://www.php.net/gd the following comment is written:

IE doesn't show TIFF files and standard PHP distribution doesn't support converting to/from TIFF.

ImageMagick (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is a free software that can read, convert and write images in a large variety of formats. For Windows users it includes a PHP extension php_magickwand_st.dll (and yes, it runs under PHP 5.0.4).

When converting from TIFF to JPEG, you must also convert from CMYK color space to RGB color space as IE can't show CMYK JPGs either. Please note:
-TIFF files may have RGB or CMYK color space
-JPEG files may have RGB or CMYK color space

Here are example functions using ImageMagick extension:
- convert TIFF to JPEG file formats
- convert CMIK to RGB color space
- set image resolution to 300 DPIs (doesn't change image size in pixels)

```
<?php

function cmyk2rgb($file) {
    $mgck_wnd = NewMagickWand();
    MagickReadImage($mgck_wnd, $file);

    $img_colspc = MagickGetImageColorspace($mgck_wnd);
    if ($img_colspc == MW_CMYKColorspace) {
        echo "$file was in CMYK format<br />";
        MagickSetImageColorspace($mgck_wnd, MW_RGBColorspace);
    }
    MagickWriteImage($mgck_wnd, str_replace('.', '-rgb.', $file));
}

function tiff2jpg($file) {
    $mgck_wnd = NewMagickWand();
    MagickReadImage($mgck_wnd, $file);

    $img_colspc = MagickGetImageColorspace($mgck_wnd);
    if ($img_colspc == MW_CMYKColorspace) {
        echo "$file was in CMYK format<br />";
        MagickSetImageColorspace($mgck_wnd, MW_RGBColorspace);
    }
    MagickSetImageFormat($mgck_wnd, 'JPG' );
    MagickWriteImage($mgck_wnd, str_replace('.tif', '.jpg', $file));
}

function to300dpi($file) {
    $mgck_wnd = NewMagickWand();
    MagickReadImage($mgck_wnd, $file);
    $img_units = MagickGetImageUnits($mgck_wnd);
    switch ($img_units) {
        case MW_UndefinedResolution: $units= 'undefined'; break;
        case MW_PixelsPerInchResolution: $units= 'PPI'; break;
        case MW_PixelsPerCentimeterResolution: $units= 'PPcm'; break;
    }
    list($x_res, $y_res) = MagickGetImageResolution($mgck_wnd);
    echo "$file<br /> x_res=$x_res $units - y_res=$y_res $units<br />";
    if($x_res == 300 && $y_res == 300 && $img_units == MW_PixelsPerInchResolution) {return; }
    MagickSetImageResolution($mgck_wnd, 300 , 300);
    MagickSetImageUnits($mgck_wnd, MW_PixelsPerInchResolution);
    MagickWriteImage($mgck_wnd, str_replace('.', '-300.', $file));
}

$file='photos/test-cmyk.tif';
//this is a TIFF file in CMYK format with a 96 DPI resolution

cmyk2rgb($file);
$file = str_replace('.', '-rgb.', $file);

to300dpi($file);
$file = str_replace('.', '-300.', $file);

tiff2jpg($file);
$file = str_replace('.tif', '.jpg', $file);

to300dpi($file);
/* no file name changes as ImageMagick reports 300 DPIs
$file = str_replace('.', '-300.', $file);
*/

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($file);
$width = $width/3;
$height = $height/3;
echo "<img src=\"http://localhost/$file\" width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\" alt=\"getimagesize() example\" />";
echo "<br />$file => width=$width - height=$height - type=$type - attr=$attr<br /><br />";

$file='photos/test-rgb.tif';
//this is a TIFF file in RGB format with a 96 DPI resolution

cmyk2rgb($file);
$file = str_replace('.', '-rgb.', $file);

to300dpi($file);
$file = str_replace('.', '-300.', $file);

tiff2jpg($file);
$file = str_replace('.tif', '.jpg', $file);

to300dpi($file);
/* no file name changes as ImageMagick reports 300 DPIs
$file = str_replace('.', '-300.', $file);
*/

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($file);
$width = $width/3;
$height = $height/3;
echo "<img src=\"http://localhost/$file\" width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\" alt=\"getimagesize() example\" />";
echo "<br />$file => width=$width - height=$height - type=$type - attr=$attr<br /><br />";

?>
```

Note - Although ImageMagick correctly sets JPEG files resolution to 300 DPIs, some programs might not notice it.

**ELSE**

Use the "imagick" PECL extension

http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Depending on sources and destinations (files? urls? http response?) you'll do something like:

```
 $image = new Imagick('something.tiff');
    $image->setImageFormat('png');
    echo $image;
```

OR

```
$image->writeImage('something.png');
```

Comment: Look at the ELSE part. Also I have mentioned at the top where it was taken "In the forum at http://www.php.net/gd the following comment is written:"

Comment: Debian based Linux PHP install command `sudo apt-get install php-imagick`

Answer (score 3):

I solved this using "convert" and ImageMagick, rather than having to install it as a DLL. Which was actually the best decision ever, because it solved the problem for PDFs as well. So I simply use:

```
$command = "convert ".$filename."[0] ".$destination;
exec($command);
```

The [0] is there for PDFs, so it will always take the first page, but it works as is for TIFF too.

All you need now is to have 'convert' on your Windows Machine and the above PHP will work for both. So simply install [this](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows).

Comment: Please ensure that `$filename` and `$destination` variables content is trusted. Using `exec` with user-provided content is dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Tifs can have more than one page so a more comprehensive approach is needed. Here is an example:

```
    //given uploaded file $filename    
    $ext = strtolower(substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1));

    if ($ext == 'tif' || $ext == 'tiff') {
        $images = new Imagick($upload_path . $filename);

        //if you want to delete the original tif
        unlink($upload_path . $filename);

        $name = strtolower(substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '.')));
        $filename = $name . '.png';
        foreach ($images as $i => $image) {
            $image->setImageFormat("png");
            $image->writeImage($upload_path . $i . $filename);
        }
    }
```