# Convert TIFF pictures automatically in php

Tags: php, jpeg, tiff

I have a folder path full of images which will be loaded by a gallery script in PHP (I create thumbnails and everything works).

Unfortunately I have TIFF pictures too in the folder.

Is there any way to convert these pictures from TIFF to JPEG automatically for showing purposes?

Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: so answer, imagemagick -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342355/convert-tiff-to-jpg-in-php

Comment: Hi Marco! I cannot get the answer from that page. I checked the link already before posting. Can you give me some help? Thank in advance!

Comment: Use ImageMagick, the link above in the first answer got a code to convert Tiff to Jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ImageMagick's `mogrify` to convert all your TIFFs into JPEGs in one go:

```
mogrify -format jpg *tif
```

Comment: Hi @Mark, this is I think what I am trying to find! I still cannot add my ImageMagick into my use. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows + Wamp. This command you told me is under Linux right?

Comment: You can download it for free for Windows here... http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows

Comment: Perfect! Now how can I call that sentence you gave me? Directly over my php script? Of course its not working. Thanks!

Comment: You start a `Command Prompt` and navigate to the directory (folder) where the TIFF files are and then you type the command and hit `Return` and it converts all the TIFFs into JPEGs.

Comment: Perfect again! Is it possible to run this command by a php file? Thanks again for your support!

Comment: You should be able to run it using PHP's `system()` command or `shell_exec()` command like this `system('mogrify -format jpg *tif');` You may need to set the correct directory first, some thing like `system('cd \images && mogrify...');`

Comment: Could you please help me on this error:        $command = 'cd:\wamp\www\FibrePrueba\01\'. $images_dir.' && mogrify -format jpg *tif';
exec($command);

Comment: Change it to `cd \wamp...` - drop the colon.