# convert base64 string to .tiff image

Tags: php, image

**Case :** I have images in `BLOB` format in database and from database getting the images in `base64` string. My code was working fine when images was `.jpeg`.

**Code:**

```
<?php $img = $image['PRODUCT_IMAGE']->load(); ?>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($img); ?>" />
```

Now suddenly my db administrator converted all images in `.tiff` format and i have to change my code to support `.tiff` format. I have been trying for solution but didn't find anything in this case.

In most scenarios they have `.tiff` file to convert [**example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342355/convert-tiff-to-jpg-in-php).

please have me achieve one of the following solution

1. Convert base64 to `.tiff` that some browser don't support.
2. Ask our DB administrator to change the format of all images.

As you guess i don't have the solution to 1 and 2. 3 is not likely to happen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342355/convert-tiff-to-jpg-in-php Just read the base64_decoded bytes into a temp file temp.tiff, read the file as given in the linked answer convert it and display.  You might not even need to write to disk, but I don't know how to make the thing expected from a bytestream.

Comment: @Tschallacka i have been trying to convert base64 to tiff file but had no luck so far. i am completely blank.

Comment: and why this question is too broad.

Comment: Seems like your base64 is a jpg image. Therefore you need to convert the base64 in jpg and then convert the jpg into tiff, by the sound of it.

Comment: @Adriano any way to convert direct to tiff

Comment: Base64 is a compression format. After you un-compress it, you get the original file; in your case (I believe) it's a jpg file.

Comment: @Adriano its not jpg file its a tiff. I have successful convert jpg file but i am not able to convert tiff file

Comment: Can you share the base64 code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163940/discussion-between-xitas-and-adriano).