# Jquery - File Upload Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I would like to upload tiff files to my webserver. I have modified the plugin to accept these files. The problem is the thumbnail doesn't create.

I don't sure that this plugin can make thumbnails to tiff files. I have read the official guide but I don't see the allowed files.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki

I revised the files of the plugin and the UploadHandler.php is the file to apply different actions, for example the creation of the thumbnail.

In this file there are a different conditions and the tiff file doesn't appear, for example in fix_file_extension:

```
protected function fix_file_extension($file_path, $name, $size, $type, $error,
            $index, $content_range) {
        // Add missing file extension for known image types:
        if (strpos($name, '.') === false &&
                preg_match('/^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)/', $type, $matches)) {
            $name .= '.'.$matches[1];
        }
        if ($this->options['correct_image_extensions'] &&
                function_exists('exif_imagetype')) {
            switch (@exif_imagetype($file_path)){
                case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                    $extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg');
                    break;
                case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                    $extensions = array('png');
                    break;
                case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                    $extensions = array('gif');
                    break;
            }
            // Adjust incorrect image file extensions:
            if (!empty($extensions)) {
                $parts = explode('.', $name);
                $extIndex = count($parts) - 1;
                $ext = strtolower(@$parts[$extIndex]);
                if (!in_array($ext, $extensions)) {
                    $parts[$extIndex] = $extensions[0];
                    $name = implode('.', $parts);
                }
            }
        }
        return $name;
    }
```

Or in create the thumbnail:

```
protected function gd_create_scaled_image($file_name, $version, $options) {
        if (!function_exists('imagecreatetruecolor')) {
            error_log('Function not found: imagecreatetruecolor');
            return false;
        }
        list($file_path, $new_file_path) =
            $this->get_scaled_image_file_paths($file_name, $version);
        $type = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1));
        switch ($type) {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg':
                $src_func = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
                $write_func = 'imagejpeg';
                $image_quality = isset($options['jpeg_quality']) ?
                    $options['jpeg_quality'] : 75;
                break;
            case 'gif':
                $src_func = 'imagecreatefromgif';
                $write_func = 'imagegif';
                $image_quality = null;
                break;
            case 'png':
                $src_func = 'imagecreatefrompng';
                $write_func = 'imagepng';
                $image_quality = isset($options['png_quality']) ?
                    $options['png_quality'] : 9;
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
```

So now I do not know how to approach it, I'm not sure if it is capable or not of creating images in low of a tiff file?

If it was not, should I use third-party libraries, ImageMagic, to create a tiff jpeg? Exactly in the code where you should create that jpg?

UPDATE:

I have installed the imagemagick library, Debian Steps:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php-imagick
```

Then the plugin doesn't show error message but the browser doesn't display tiff files.

My idea would be upload tiff files and create jpg files as thumbnails of these tiff files and it use these jpg for show in browser. The problem is that I don't know to create thumbnails of all tiff files in jpg files using this plugin :(

Thanks!

Comment: check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342355/convert-tiff-to-jpg-in-php

Comment: @NicolòCozzani thanks for your response. Already I have read this post. I know to convert tiff to jpg using imagemagic But the question is: the file upload plugin can convert tiff to jpg? If not Where I implemented imagemagic in the plugin code?

Comment: If with _plugin_ you mean the jquery plugin, i dont think you can convert images. can you show the piece of php code that actually save data on server side?

Comment: The plugin upload tiff file correctly but I doesn't create the thumbnail image from tiff file to jpg file.